# Exception Error for Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, user, collaborationgroup

I have this trigger where it adds new user to chatter group but it throws exceptions everytime when i reset the password or when i deactivate any user, how can i update the trigger to not throw any exceptions?

Trigger:

```
trigger CompanyChatter on User (after insert, after update) {
    UserMethods.addToMainGroup(trigger.newMap.keySet());
}
```

Apex class:

```
public class UserMethods {

    @future
    public static void addToMainGroup(Set<Id> userIds) {
     List<User> users=[select id, Username from User where id in :userIds];

     CollaborationGroup chatterGroup=[select Id from CollaborationGroup Where Name='My Company, Inc'];
     List<CollaborationGroupMember> chatterGroupMembers=new List<CollaborationGroupMember>();

     for(User user: users){
         CollaborationGroupMember newMember = new CollaborationGroupMember(CollaborationGroupId=chatterGroup.id, MemberId = user.Id, NotificationFrequency = 'P');
         chatterGroupMembers.add(newMember);
     }
    if(!Test.isRunningTest()){
     insert chatterGroupMembers;
     }
    }

}
```

**Exceptions**

For Reset passwords:

> Developer script exception from SonoSite, Inc : 'UserMethods' for job id '7073300002yuF1b' : Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: DUPLICATE_VALUE, User is already a Member of this group.: [MemberId]

When i deactivate users:

> First error: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INACTIVE_OWNER_OR_USER, operation performed with inactive user [00540000002ome5]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to filter your `User` records so you only create a `CollaborationGroupMember` when one is appropriate. That involves two steps:

1. Make sure the `User` record is active.
2. Make sure there is no associated `CollaborationGroupMember`.

You can verify both of the above by modifying the `SOQL` for your `User` query.

```
List<User> users = [
    SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Id IN :userIds AND IsActive = true AND Id NOT IN (
        SELECT MemberId FROM CollaborationGroupMember
        WHERE CollaborationGroup.Name = 'My Company, Inc'
    )
];
```

Comment: How can i just modify above trigger to avoid exceptions?

Comment: @Admin_BA Why can't you modify the class? Regardless, I added how you can use `Apex` to get what you need.

Comment: Sorry i didn't meant to downvote, iam still new to this site. How do i modify my existing class to include this? i didn't meant trigger

Comment: @Admin_BA You just put the query inside your square brackets. `List<User> users = [/*query*/]`.